# Can I enroll in FSA after losing coverage due to my father losing his job?

Tags: united-states, insurance, healthcare, fsa, hsa

I am being allowed by my employer to enroll in a Health Insurance plan outside of the open enrollment period or new hire period due to an Involuntary Loss of Coverage (my father lost his job and I was a dependent on his plan).

However, they are telling me that my event is not a qualifying event to enroll in an FSA, and I do not agree with this. Why would enrolling in a Health Insurance plan be OK, and enrolling in an FSA not?

I have read all the tables explaining which events quality for mid-year FSA enrollment and which do not, but none of them take into account the person in question previously being a dependent on someone else's health plan.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you've answered your own question.  The [qualifying events](http://www.mycafeteriaplan.com/employee/fsa-account-rules/#csma) for changing your FSA coverage specifically do not have anything to do with your health insurance or lack thereof.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I am not allowed to...

Comment: Looks like it.  :(  Remember, the only connection between an FSA and medical insurance is that in the US both happen to be (inexplicably!) provided through one's employer.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the rules regarding FSAs are in the form "permitted, but not required." An employer can offer an FSA with a lower maximum deposit, for example. 
It's my understanding that while they might be legally *required* to allow you to enroll in the medical plan, the FSA can have a different enrollment criteria.